# How do you say you were "promoted to the next/following grade in school" in a way that sounds natural?

Tags: word-choice

How do you say you were "promoted to the next/following grade in school" in a way that sounds natural?

'Promoted' doesn't sound natural to me, but maybe it is..? Does "moved to the next grade" sound better?

I've never really read those expressions so I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back when I was in elementary school in the U.S., the schools did call it "promotion". On your last report card of the year, it would say (hopefully) that you had been "promoted" to the next grade.

Checking youtube and other parts of the internet, I see that many school districts still refer to "promotion to the next grade level".

Of course we laymen would probably say something less formal, like "moved up" or "advanced" to the next grade. But I don't think it's wrong (at least in the U.S.) to use the educational terminology of "promotion". Don't know about other countries.

Answer (score 0):

In American English we do not talk of people being **promoted to the next grade**. Instead the default assumption is that they have passed all the necessary classes and have **completed their current grade**, but even that is not really discussed much because it is the default assumption. The opposite is when someone is **held back a year**.

Comment: Check the internet; I think we do talk of students being "promoted" to [x] grade. Youtube is full of videos of school promotion ceremonies. E.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaJdvG2M5N8

Answer (score 0):

In English, English, normally you are just in a ~"year"

> He's a first year,

*His is in his first year*

then you would just automatically be a *"second year"* the next year.

Although I do recognise the American influence in schools the word Grade sometimes being used. But my granddaughters school website still denotes things the UK way;

Year 1, Year 2, etc.

I suppose you could be promoted to a prefect, but in English you are normally just made a "Prefect". How one could be promoted to another year I do not comprehend. I also have never know anyone to moved to the next year. "Years" are age based not performance.

Comment: Looks like this one is indeed tough. I'm a native Spanish speaker, but the original sentence is in Japanese; it looks like both Spanish and Japanese educative system makes it possible to have an expression like the one I'm looking for, whereas English doesn't seem to have it. The idea is being able to say "I met the requirements to complete the previous (?) grade and therefore started the following one", without stating which level/grade one is referring to (and without explaining this much either).

Comment: I am not currently in the education system; and unless things have changed drastically and I don't know about it. Moving to the next year depends on age. Ability is dealt with by the level of the class you are in. Anything out of the "norm" being dealt with by special needs classes or  establishments. Therefore there is no promotion as such just progression.